Latent heat transfer coefficient over the ocean?
I'm currently calculating for the surface turbulent latent heat flux over the Pacific. The formula I have needs a $C_E$ which is the latent heat transfer coefficient.
I've read several studies that state that this coefficient depends on the wind speed. ChatGPT gave me the formula  $C_{E} = 0.0012 \times  \sqrt{V}$ where V is the wind speed.
This formula gave me identical surface turbulent latent heat flux values to the study I'm replicating (https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2017JD027557). However, when I use other C_E values I found ranging from 0.0011 to 0.00135, the surface latent heat flux becomes really small and isn't anywhere close to the study I'm following.
Any idea where ChatGPT got that formula from? Is it even a real formula.

Respectfully, what is your physics-related question? Who knows where ChatGPT got that response—that application is a sophisticated autocomplete designed to sound correct, not to be correct.

@Chemomechanics I know that ChatGPT's response is wrong. I'm just wondering if there are any studies that define C_E as a function of wind speed instead of a constant, much like what ChatGPT provided.

what is the difference between the heat transfer coefficient and the latent heat transfer coefficient?
